# Spatial analysis in ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, spatial

Im user of Oracle SQL Developer and I still try to find if i can execute spatial analysis in that software... I have two spatial data tables and I need to execute overlay analysis between these tables. Has anybody experiences with spatial analysis in SQL Developer and how can I execute that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's both too broad, and not really a programming, but a database usage question.

Comment: Its not too broad, I can apply that on exact example if you have not problem with that, right? I have one spatial table with line features and second table with polygon features. If feature from first table is fully contain in polygon from second table then I wanna put name of concrete polygon to concrete line feature...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it there in PLSQL. 
You should look at the SDO_GEOM package, and the SDO_RELATE function like this:

```
select * from
tableA a, tableB b
where sdo_relate(a.geomColumn,b.geomColumn,'mask=anyinteract')='TRUE';
```

there are different interact masks as well....and you should know this is a terrible query example from an optimization perspective, I'm just trying to get you started in a direction.

Also, if you want to actually get the intersecTION of the two layers, then use the SDO_INTERSECTION function in a somewhat similar way.

Oracle spatial is awesome, extensive, and vast... good luck!
HTH